# how to rename column after summarise by sum?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to rename a column name after conducting summarise(sum)

The code as it is now is the follow

```
Tix <- GoT %>%
  filter(Total_Tickets_Purchased >= 1) %>%
  group_by(DayDif) %>% 
  summarise(sum(Total_Tickets_Purchased))
```

This calculates everything correctly but the column name is sum(Total_Tickets_Purchased). When conducting further code, it is not recognizing it as the column name

I have tried to following code to do so.

```
Tix <- GoT %>%
  filter(Total_Tickets_Purchased >= 1) %>%
  group_by(DayDif) %>% 
  summarise(sum(Total_Tickets_Purchased)) %>% 
  rename(c[,2] = Total)
```

This results in the following error

```
error: unexpected '=' in:
"  summarise(sum(Total_Tickets_Purchased)) %>% 
  rename(c[,2] ="
```

Does anyone have advice?

Comment: Try `summarise(Total = sum(Total_Tickets_Purchased))` or `rename(Total = 2)` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Tix <- GoT %>%
  filter(Total_Tickets_Purchased >= 1) %>%
  group_by(DayDif) %>% 
  summarise(Total = sum(Total_Tickets_Purchased))
```